# How to pass a php code in a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to append the name of the file uploaded into ('.list'). The name of the file has to be the name which it is called in the server when it is uploaded. For example I could have 2 files but one is known as mountains.png and the other mountains2.png.

But the problem is that how could I pass $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"] as argument to my js function and then append it because the javascript function and the php script are on seperate pages (even though the php script does do a call back to the javascript function)?

**UPDATE**

Below is the javascript code:

Below is the form code (QandATable.php)

```
<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
        <p>Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' />
        <input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' />
        </p> 
        <ul class='list'></ul>
        </form>
```

Below is the javascript function (QandATable.php)

```
      function stopImageUpload(success){

  var nameimagefile = <?php echo $nameimagefile?>;
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
         $('.listImage').append(nameimagefile + '<br/>');
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

     return true;

    }
```

Below is the php script (imageupload.php):

```
   $result = 0;
    $nameimagefile = '';

        if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
            $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
            $ext = array_pop($parts);
            $base = implode(".",$parts);
            $n = 2;

            while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
            $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
            "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
            $result = 1;
$nameimagefile = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"];

        }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
              "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
              $result = 1;
$nameimagefile = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"];

              }


        ?>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Comment: you'll have to look into ajax for that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the value $_FILE filename into a php variable than echo it using

```
var yourjasvariable=<?php echo $yourvariable?>;
```

and use this js variable in append method. :-)

Comment: Just one quick question, does the $yourvariable = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]; goes in the php script page (imageupload.php) or does it go on the same page as the javascript function?

Comment: Well. If you use 2 different pages you should look through Ajax/JSON for exchanging data between Javascript and PHP

Comment: pass the name of file as another argument, you can use array if more than one file is there. $yourvariable = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]; this will exists only in your imageupload.php. Thanks

Comment: I have tried what you have said but problem is that it comes with an error: invalid regular expression flag when I tried the code above

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I have included the codes for the form, javascript and php in the question. Hopefully that is all of the information you need :)

Comment: Please try to use other variable in "  $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext; " And then use this variable in  move_uploaded_file function. I think u are overriding this variable. Please try. Thanx

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I have updated code in question, still comes up with same error tho :( . Is it because the php and javascript function are on seperate pages that this problem is occuring?

Comment: @user1324106 Hey you did not pass that variable in your js function. Try like this   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopImageUpload('<?php echo $result;?>','<?php echo $nameimagefile $?>');</script>, Please always pass string values in quotes in Javascript function. Thanks . Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could chose AJAX to do what you want. 
Write your data in JSON.  JSON can be read from PHP and JavaScript
- read the JSON to get data in PHP
- read the AJAX result (the JSON) to get the data from PHP

I would do something like this (untested example)

## AJAX js part

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit='startAjaxImageUpload(this);' >
      ...
</form>  

/*
 * ajax functions 
 */
function startAjaxImageUpload(event){

    /* Collect your formdatas as json with jquery this datas will be sent to php*/
    var formDatas = {
            'value1'        : $('input[test1=eid]').val(),
            'value2'        : $('input[id=test2_id]').val(),
            ......
        'value3'    : $('input[id=test3_id]').val()
        };

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url:  "imageupload",
        data: formDatas,
        success: function(data) {
            // data is the json Result from php => imageupload.php do what u want with them in js
            // use the next line if u wanna see which json datas comes back from php if the ajax call wass successfull
            // console.log("data is %o, data);
            // ....

        }
        error:function(data){
            // error function
            // data is the json Result from php => imageupload.php do what u want with them in js
            // use the next line if u wanna see which json datas comes back from php if the ajax call wass successfull
            // console.log("data is %o, data);
            alert(damn, something went wrong);
        }
    })
}
```

## PHP part, imageupload.php

```
    $result = 0;
    $nameimagefile = '';
    .....
    // if done ure work on server side and no error was found, pass the  result back to starAjaxImageUpload success function
    return $nameimagefile = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"];
    }else
    // abbort ajax, ajax error function will used
    return false
          }
```